# How to truncate nanoseconds to milliseconds with sed

Tags: bash, sed, text-processing

I have a csv file containing time stamps in the format of `2011-01-01 12:30:10.123456+00` and I want to remove the last 3 digits of the nanosecond, to get `2011-01-01 12:30:10.123+00` .

How can I accomplish this with sed or a similar tool?

A caveat would be that sometimes the precision varies. I want to only keep the first three digits of the nanosecond following the period.

Thank you!

Comment: Do we need to have some form of rouding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `gnu sed` will keep the 3 first digit and remove all others:

```
cat file
2011-01-01 12:30:10.123456+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.12+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.1+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.12345678+00

sed -r "s/(\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g" file
2011-01-01 12:30:10.123+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.12+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.1+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.123+00
```

A shorter version of Pacifists post:

```
sed "s/\.*[0-9][0-9][0-9]+/+/g" file #original
sed "s/[0-9]\{3\}+/+/g" file         #Shorter version

2011-01-01 12:30:10.123+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.12+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.1+00
2011-01-01 12:30:10.12345+00  #Both version gives more than 3 digits if its more than 6 total
```

Comment: Your first answer is good, except that it should be noted that `sed -r` is GNU notation, and is not universal. Heck, support for ERE in sed is not universal.

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "s/(\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g": \1 not defined in the RE` when running your version Jotne `echo "2019-07-18 18:11:12.33244+00" | sed "s/(\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g"`
Why does `echo "2019-07-18 18:11:12.33244+00" | sed "s/[0-9]\{3\}+/+/g"` (shorter version of Pacifist) result in only 2 digits being kept after the period?

Comment: @JW2 You get tow digits, since input has only 5 and this solution removes the last three digits. First one fails since you miss the `-r`  so it should be `echo "2019-07-18 18:11:12.33244+00" | sed -r "s/(\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g"`

Comment: How could you modify to keep the first three digits and remove the remaining up to the `+`. In the original question I wanted to keep the first 3 digits. The solutions so far seem to be removing the last 3 like you said.

Comment: `sed -r "s/(\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g" file` my first solution does that.  It starts to look for number after `.` and will keep up to three digits.

Comment: Huh, thanks for clarifying. I still get an error `sed: illegal option -- r` when running your solution.

Comment: Modifying it by adding backslashes to escape the parens seems to work, as well as dropping the -r `echo "2019-07-18 18:11:12.33+00" | sed  "s/\(\.[0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g"`

Comment: @Jotne Can you help build the regex out a little bit to protect against truncating other values, and limiting it only to timestamps? Currently if I have anything like `1.0042` in my file it will also be truncated. I think this accomplishes that, but a second eye would help! `sed  "s/\([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g"`

Comment: Just grab more of the time format like this  `sed -r "s/(([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g"`  If this help you upvote the answer or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
var="2011-01-01 12:30:10.123456+00"
echo $var | sed "s/\.*[0-9][0-9][0-9]+/+/g"
```

Comment: Sorry, edited. 

Can you check my understanding? 

- The first `\.` escapes the period
- The `*` matches [0-9] zero or more times
- The first `+` matches one or more of the prior [0-9]?

How does the `/+/` work?

Comment: it definitely does, just want to confirm my understanding so I can think about the corner cases. Thank you!

Comment: Can you help me understand how the regex works? I understand the general syntax is `sed "/matchgroup1/matchgroup2/g"`, but I don't understand how the replacement is happening. The second match group seems like it's just a `+`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199711/discussion-between-pacifist-and-jw2).

Comment: @JW2 and @Pacifist, that's not how this regex works at all. Sed, by default, interprets BASIC RE. So the `+` is literal, not "one or more" of the previous atom. In this case, the `*` makes the dot optional, and the script strips out the three characters before the `+`. Try this solution with `var="2011-01-01 12:30:10.1234+00"`